# Invertibility of the linear operator?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

I am given with partial differential equation $$-(au_x)_x+cu= f \qquad u(0) = u(1) = 0$$ where $a \in H^1[0,1]$ sobolev space, $c, f \in L^2[0,1]$, $c \geq 0 $ a.e. and $a \geq p > 0$.

Now for $a$ as defined above we have an operator $$A(a): H^2\cap H^1_0 \to L^2$$ defined by $$A(a)\phi = -(a\phi_x)_x +c\phi$$ Now Clearly $A(a)$ is a linear operator. I have question that is it possible to write the following equation as this involves inverse of operator $A(a)$ $$A(a)u = -(au_x)_x+cu = f \implies u = A(a)^{-1}f$$ Is $A(a)$ invertible or how it is written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is solved by Theorem 4.22 in [these lecture notes](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch4.pdf). You should notice that $a \in L^\infty(0,1)$ by the Sobolev Embedding Theorem, and that the assumption $a \geq p>0$ implies the coercivity of the associates bilinear form.

Anyway, you could also minimize
$$
I(u) = \frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 a(x) |u'(x)|^2 \, dx + \frac{c}{2} \int_0^1 |u(x)|^2 \, dx - \int_0^1 f(x)u(x)\, dx
$$
on $H_0^1(0,1)$ and show that there exists one and only one minimizer $u$. Then you could prove that this minimizer solves the boundary value problem and belongs to $H^2(0,1)$.

Comment: Can you please also tell me  can i expand $u(c+h)$ in powers of $h$ of not?

Comment: @kapil What do you mean?

Comment: Can you please have a look at this? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2055264/how-to-find-out-frechet-derivative-of-the-following-operator

Comment: Will be grateful to you. Thanks in advance